# How to change the button color with bash code return

Tags: php, bash, button

Hello I'm working on a web page on PHP and one of its duties is checking a linux service status and if it's running showing a message about the status. I'm returning the value to the web page with shell_exec() function. But I don't know how to use that value after.

I need to place two buttons that are going to change the status:

- If the service is running red "Stop" button will stop it with a bash code and the grey "Run" button's color will change to green.
- If the service is not running then green "Run" button will run it and grey "Stop" button's color is change to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX to get the status from server, and according to the response status change the button color by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if your service is running, you can use linux command `pgrep` for that

> ```
>    MAN: pgrep  looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.
> ```

Assuming you know process name, you can check it like that:

```
$p = shell_exec("pgrep $pname");
if(!$p) {
.....
}
```